# How to read and change big arr in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state that contains another array. I need to get this array to return it as a list. The new Item should appear as an object in the application array. I don't quite understand what I did wrong. How can I fix this?
** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZQsD.png)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
        name: 'Ivan Pupkin',
        email: 'ivan@gmail.com',
        phone: '+34452344323',
        application: [
            {
                nameOfApp: 'Name of App',
                type: 'It and business',
                description: 'some description', 
            },
        ],
    },
]) 
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [type, setType] = useState('');
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('');

  const addNewUser = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    setData(current => current.map(item => [...item.application, {
      personalId: 4,
      nameOfApp: name,
      description: description,
      type: type
    }]))
  }
  const Users = data.map(item => item.application.map((elem, index) => {
      return(
        <div key={index}>
          <div>{elem.nameOfApp}</div>
          <div>{elem.type}</div>
          <div>{elem.description}</div>
        </div>
      )
  }))


  return (
    <div>
      <form action="#">
        <input onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} placeholder='name'/>
        <input onChange={(e) => setType(e.target.value)} placeholder='type'/>
        <input onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)} placeholder='desc'/>
        <button onClick={addNewUser} type='submit'>submit</button>
      </form>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      {Users}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Change it how? To read it you just have to use `data` or print it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've understand what you're tring to do but here is a working version :

Basically, I just say which user I want to edit in addUser() then search it, assign new application to it, and return the array of users without the previous user

If I were you, I would avoid to have objects / array without ids :)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Ivan Pupkin",
      email: "ivan@gmail.com",
      phone: "+34452344323",
      application: [
        {
          id: 1,
          nameOfApp: "Name of App",
          type: "It and business",
          description: "some description"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [type, setType] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");

  const addNewUser = (e, targetUserId) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setData((prevUsers) => {
      const editedUser = prevUsers.find(({ id }) => id === targetUserId);
      editedUser.application.push({
        nameOfApp: name,
        type: type,
        description: description
      });
      const newUsers = [
        ...prevUsers.filter(({ id }) => id !== targetUserId),
        editedUser
      ];
      return newUsers;
    });
  };
  const Users = data.map((item) =>
    item.application.map((elem, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index}>
          <div>{elem.nameOfApp}</div>
          <div>{elem.type}</div>
          <div>{elem.description}</div>
        </div>
      );
    })
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <form action="#">
        <input onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} placeholder="name" />
        <input onChange={(e) => setType(e.target.value)} placeholder="type" />
        <input
          onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="desc"
        />
        <button onClick={(e) => addNewUser(e, 1)} type="submit">
          submit
        </button>
      </form>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      {Users}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Hope it helped you !